# how to get the number from url like this: index?5

Tags: php, variables

if I have url:

```
site.com/index.php?t=12
```

i cant get 12 with $_get['t']
but if the url like this:

```
site.com/index.php?12
```

how to get if
and if it's like this

```
site.com/index.php?t12
```

how to get the number
thanks

Comment: `var_dump($_SERVER);`

Comment: That's a bad way to structure your URLs, too ambiguous and might interfere when you want to add more data to the query string.

Comment: why are you doing it that way? why not just use the first example?

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
$str = array_keys($_GET)[0]; // PHP 5.4 and up
list($str) = array_keys($_GET); // all versions
```

From there you can parse out the number just like any other string: `preg_replace("/\D/","",$str);`

Comment: Alternative < 5.4 syntax: `current(array_keys($_GET))`

Comment: @WesleyMurch Edited in my own alternative <5.4

Comment: If this answer helped, please mark is as Accepted by clicking the check mark to the left of it. For more information, see the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Answer (score 1):

The old-fashioned way to access a plain non-parameter value after the `?` is:

```
print $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"];
```

Suitable if there is assuredly just your `t12`.

Answer (score 0):

URL: `http://yoursite.com/index.php?t12`

```
print_r($_SERVER);
>>
$_SERVER: Array
    [QUERY_STRING] => t12
    [REQUEST_METHOD] => GET
    [SCRIPT_NAME] => /index.php
    [REQUEST_URI] => /index.php?t12
    [DOCUMENT_URI] => /index.php
```

You can combine `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` and Kolink's answer. Additionally, depending on the possibilities for the non-numeric portions of the string, you can also use `trim()` with a character mask, `explode('t',$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])`. My personal preference is to use explode and trim.